# Lex: expected expression before ‘[’ token when writing regular expressions

Tags: flex-lexer, lex

I'm new to [Lex](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lex_(software))/[Yacc](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yacc) and am following this tutorial: *[Part 01: Tutorial on Lex/Yacc](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=54bo1qaHAfk)*

Here's my Lex file:

```
%{
    #include "main.h"
    #include <stdio.h>
%}

%%
    [a-zA-Z][_a-zA-Z0-9]*   {return IDENTIFIER;}
    "&"                     {return RUN_DAEMON;}
    "|"                     {return SYM_PIPE;}
    ">"                     {return RED_STDOUT;}
    "<"                     {return RED_STDIN;}
    ">>"                    {return APP_STDOUT;}
    [ \t\n]+                {;}
    .                       {printf("unexpected character\n");}
%%

int yywrap(){
    return 1;
}
```

However, after running the `lex` command, I try to compile `lex.yy.c` with `gcc`, but it spams me with this error:

```
sbash.l: In function ‘yylex’:
sbash.l:7:5: error: expected expression before ‘[’ token
     [a-zA-Z][_a-zA-Z0-9]*   {return IDENTIFIER;}
     ^
sbash.l:7:6: error: ‘a’ undeclared (first use in this function)
     [a-zA-Z][_a-zA-Z0-9]*   {return IDENTIFIER;}
      ^
sbash.l:7:6: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in
sbash.l:7:14: error: ‘_a’ undeclared (first use in this function)
     [a-zA-Z][_a-zA-Z0-9]*   {return IDENTIFIER;}
              ^~
sbash.l:7:17: error: ‘zA’ undeclared (first use in this function)
     [a-zA-Z][_a-zA-Z0-9]*   {return IDENTIFIER;}
                 ^~
sbash.l:7:20: error: ‘Z0’ undeclared (first use in this function)
     [a-zA-Z][_a-zA-Z0-9]*   {return IDENTIFIER;}
                    ^~
sbash.l:7:29: error: expected expression before ‘{’ token
     [a-zA-Z][_a-zA-Z0-9]*   {return IDENTIFIER;}
                             ^
sbash.l:13:7: error: stray ‘\’ in program
     [ \t\n]+                {;}
       ^
sbash.l:13:9: error: stray ‘\’ in program
     [ \t\n]+                {;}
```

Unfortunately, I cannot find what's going wrong even when googled (many example's expression writes exactly the same as my code).

My Lex version is 2.6.1 and is on [CentOS 8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CentOS#CentOS_version_8).

Comment: You need to use flex to generate a C program from your .l file. If you feed the scanner description to the C compiler, you can indeed expect a lot of errors, since it is not a C program. Your video link spams me with ads I don't want to see, so I didn't pursue it further. For a good gentle introduction to writing scanner descriptions, you could try reading the [example code in the flex manual](http://westes.github.io/flex/manual/Simple-Examples.html#Simple-Examples).

Comment: @rici I have run `lex sbash.l` and `gcc lex.yy.c` already tho, I'll add them in op

Comment: are your lex rules really indented like that? You can't do that. See the [Flex manual](http://westes.github.io/flex/manual/Rules-Section.html#Rules-Section), which really is required reading: "The *rules* section of the flex input contains a series of rules of the form: `pattern   action` where the **pattern must be unindented** and the action must begin on the same line." (Some emphasis added)

Comment: Solved, thanks a lot! I really unexpected indentation will be a problem... please post as answer so I can mark as solution, thanks again. And yeah, I should really rtfm next time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As explained in the [Flex manual chapter on flex input file format](http://westes.github.io/flex/manual/Rules-Section.html#Rules-Section), pattern rules must start at the left margin:

> The *rules* section of the flex input contains a series of rules of the form:
>
> ```
>   pattern   action
> ```
>
> where **the pattern must be unindented** and the action must begin on the same line. (Some emphasis added)

Indented lines on the rules section are just passed through as-is. In particular, indented lines prior to the first rule are inserted at the top of the `yylex` function, which is frequently useful. But flex makes no attempt to verify that code included in this way is valid; errors will be detected when the generated scanner is compiled.